# HTML do JSON n é reconhecido em função de plugins

Tags: php, javascript

Eu fiz um *JSON* chamando umas informações do banco de dados, porém eu fui usar um *plugin* de *slide* e não funciona. Mas parece q não é só ele, com outros tipos de função também, parece que ele não reconhece os id ou class. Mas se eu fizer no *HTML* normal, funciona.

```html
<div class="swiper-container" id="leitor">
    <div id="leitor2"></div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-white"></div>
    <!-- Add Navigation -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>

<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/swiper.js"></script>
<script src="js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/swiper.esm.js"></script>
<script src="js/swiper.esm.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            zoom: true,
            lazy: true,
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination',
            },
            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var container = $("#leitor");
  var lista = container.find("#leitor2");
  var html = '';


  var query = location.search.slice(1);
  var partesDaQuery = query.split("&");
  var json = {};

    partesDaQuery.forEach(function(partes){
        var chaveValor = partes.split('=');
        var paramsKey = chaveValor[0];
        var paramsValue = chaveValor[1];
        json[paramsKey] = paramsValue;

        $.getJSON('http://teste.com/app2.php?id='+json[paramsKey], 
            function(data){
                $.each(data, function(k, v){
                html +=  '<div class="swiper-slide">';
                html +=    '<div class="swiper-zoom-container">';
                //Essa parte da imagem ainda não acabei.
                  html +=    
                    '<img src="http://teste.com/leitor/capa/'+v.titulo+'/170/01.jpg" class="swiper-lazy">';
                  html +=     
                    '<div class="swiper-lazy-preloader swiper-lazy-preloader-white"></div>';
                  html += '</div>';
                    });
                lista.html(html);
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Você está falando desse getJSON do final? E qual é o JSON que ele está recebendo?

Comment: Sim. Então o JSON tá funcionando, mas o script parece q n reconhece a class q tá dentro desse JSON. Ai não consigo dar zoom na imagem, nem passar ela:

<script  type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      zoom: true,
      lazy: true,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
    });
    });
  </script>

Comment: Como assim "classe dentro desse JSON"? Tem certeza que está entregando JSON válido para o JavaScript?

Comment: Acho q sim. Estou mexendo agr com JSON. Se tiver um exemplo melhor pra ser usado.

A class que eu me referi seria essa aqui: http://prntscr.com/hjkghc